# Return numbers in array that are less than x

Tags: ruby

I have an array of numbers:

```
arr = [1,2,3,87,99,66,44,3,5]
```

I want to select the elements from it that are less than `3`, and count them. How can I return an array with numbers from `arr` less than `3` (`[1,2]`)? Similarly, I want the numbers less than `50`: `[1,2,3,3,5,44]`.

I thought I could use `arr.min(3)`, or `arr.any? {|a| a < 3}`, which turned out to be not what I want.

Comment: Use select method on the array. arr.select{|a|a<3}

Comment: Look through the methods in `Array` and `Enumerable`. Can you guess which one you can use if you want to **select** elements? Can you guess which method you can use if you want to **count** elements?

Comment: Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is an XY-question.

What you asked for:

```
arr.select{|e| e < 3} # => [1, 2]
```

What you needed to do:

```
arr.count{|e| e < 3} # => 2
```